# Live Agent Button not visible for Community User

Tags: community, liveagent, community-builder

I have installed [Managed Package](https://test.salesforce.com/packaging/installPackage.apexp?p0=04t61000000Tmnp) which is in Lightning Component for Live Agent Implementation in Commmunity.

In Community Builder, after doing all the configuration, Button is visible perfectly. But when I logged in through the Community User, button is not visible at all.

I think that the Live Agent User checkbox is visible for Salesforce User but not for Community User.

It will be really helpful if anyone can please let me know how that button will be visible for Community User.

Comment: I installed the same package and it seems to be visible just for Salesforce logged in users. Did you manage to solve this issue?

Comment: any update? ?????